# undefined local variable or method `content_security_policy_nonce' for #<ProjectsController:0x00007fffe36513d8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, single-sign-on

I am trying to use Single Sign On App I built to login into a another rails 5 app. I get the error message below when click on the button to open the site. I am using the repost gem
[image]

Comment: `content_security_policy_nonce` was added in rails v5.2. you'll have to upgrade rails or downgrade repost gem.

Comment: Thank you, Upgrading the rails version worked!